# GeoServer GetFeature returns Features outside of Bounding Box parameters

Tags: geoserver

I was wondering if someone knows how the bounding box works in a GeoServer GetFeature request.  I'm getting points outside of the bounding box in my results.  The url below has been changed for privacy reasons.  I'd like only features returned that intersect my bounding box.  I'm using turf intersect to validate this in my code, but would like to directly retrieve only features inside the bounding box directly from GeoServer.  You notice that the point is close to the bounding box.

Is there a "default" circumference where a point has a measurable diameter?

My bounding box is as follows:
bbox=-74.06319359895673,40.69286603702574,-73.82753685229358,40.88708764740173

Example of a feature returned:

{
"type": "Feature",
"id": "273",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
-73.8032,
40.7949
]
},
"geometry_name": "SHAPE",
"properties": {
"LATITUDE": 40.771382,
"LONGITUDE": -73.754673,
"OFFICE": "ABC",
"DESC": "Construction",
}

```
    },
```

myhost/geoserver/xyz/wms?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&bbox=-
74.06319359895673,40.69286603702574,-
73.82753685229358,40.88708764740173,EPSG:4326&typeName=xyz:ABCPoints&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

Comment: what projection is your data stored in? it's probably to do with a conversion to/from WGS84. I suspect GeoServer densifies the bounding box so it curves with the earth and turf doesn't?

Comment: It is stored as NAD83